# Do I need to update the app registration to use FCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-plugin-push

I am currently using https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push version 1.11.1 on my PhoneGap app.

After I initialized the plugin using my GCM application key I get the generated registration ID and save it to later send notifications through a separate service.

if the service that sends the notification is already updated to use FCM do I need to do anything else?

After April 10, will the registration process that happens inside the app through the phonegap-plugin-push plugin stop working?

Comment: Consider using Firebase. There's a quick and easy setup on InteliJ